# Error al actualizar datos de JTable desde MYSQL con Java

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, jtable

Estoy haciendo un CRUD con Java y MYSQL, todo marcha a la perfección, hasta que trato de eliminar un registro de mi JTable con un popmenu.

Y obtengo esta excepción:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Estoy haciendo una búsqueda tipeada dentro del JTable donde estoy eliminando ese registro, si no hago la búsqueda, el registro se elimina sin problemas, pero si lo elimino buscando por tipeo, ahí es donde salta la excepción y no doy cómo solucionarlo.

Este es el código que llena mi tabla desde MYSQL:

```
public void llenaTbConsultasRetencionesEE(String numche) {
    try {

        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        modelo.addColumn("RFC");
        modelo.addColumn("NOMBRE");
        modelo.addColumn("INSTRUMENTO");
        modelo.addColumn("FOLIO");
        modelo.addColumn("PRDNAME");
        modelo.addColumn("ESTATUS");
        modelo.addColumn("NOMINA");

        frmrtC.tbConsultasRetenciones.setModel(modelo);
        String sql = "";

        if (numche.equals("")) {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM retenciones";
        } else {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM retenciones WHERE numche = '" + numche + "'";
        }

        String[] datos = new String[7];

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Conexion conn = new Conexion();
        com.mysql.jdbc.Connection con = conn.getConexion();

        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rsMd = rs.getMetaData();

        while (rs.next()) {
            datos[0] = rs.getString(1);
            datos[1] = rs.getString(2);
            datos[2] = rs.getString(3);
            datos[3] = rs.getString(4);
            datos[4] = rs.getString(5);
            datos[5] = rs.getString(6);
            datos[6] = rs.getString(7);
            modelo.addRow(datos);
        }
        frmrtC.tbConsultasRetenciones.setModel(modelo);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }
    anchoColumnasTbConsultasRetenciones();
}
```

Esta es la clase anchoColumnasTbConsultasRetenciones():

```
public void anchoColumnasTbConsultasRetenciones() {
    TableColumnModel columnModel1 = frmrtC.tbConsultasRetenciones.getColumnModel();
    columnModel1.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
    columnModel1.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(400);
    columnModel1.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(20);
    columnModel1.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(80);
    columnModel1.getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(70);
    columnModel1.getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(90);
    columnModel1.getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(90);
}
```

Esta es la clase donde hago el rowfilter para búsqueda por tipeo:

```
frmrtC.txtBuscarRetencion.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
                trs.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + frmrtC.txtBuscarRetencion.getText(), 0, 1, 3));

            }

        });

        trs = new TableRowSorter(frmrtC.tbConsultasRetenciones.getModel());
        frmrtC.tbConsultasRetenciones.setRowSorter(trs);
```

Aquí es la clase donde elimino el registro seleccionado:

```
public void eliminaRetenciones() {
    try {
        int fila = frmrtC.tbConsultasRetenciones.getSelectedRow();
        String numche = frmrtC.tbConsultasRetenciones.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Conexion conn = new Conexion();
        com.mysql.jdbc.Connection con = conn.getConexion();
        String sql = "DELETE FROM retenciones WHERE NUMCHE = '" + numche + "'";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(controladorRetenciones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Y, finalmente, aquí es donde llamo a los métodos en cuestión:

```
if (e.getSource() == frmrtC.miConsultasRetenciones) {

        if (frmrtC.txtBuscarRetencion.getText().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro eliminado con éxito.");
            eliminaRetenciones();
            llenaTbConsultasRetencionesEE("");

        } else {
            eliminaRetenciones();
            DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
            frmrtC.tbConsultasRetenciones.setModel(modelo);
            
            llenaTbConsultasRetencionesEE("");
        }

    }
```

¿Qué he intentado? Como pueden notar, donde llamo los métodos para eliminar, trato de vaciar el modelo que trae previamente, creando un modelo vacío y después volver a llamar al método que llena la tabla, pero sigo consiguiendo la excepción, ¿Alguna sugerencia, recomendación o consejo? Gracias